# Issues related to calling UIKit methods from non-main thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, web-services, grand-central-dispatch, kvnprogress

I implemented login method in this way:

```
      [KVNProgress show];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //some error handling like:
                if ([_usernameField.text length] < 4) {
                    [KVNProgress showErrorWithStatus:@"Username too short!"];
                    _passwordField.text = @"";
                    return;
                }
       //Then I call login web service synchronously here:
       result = [ServerRequests login];
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       if(!result)
                    {
                        [KVNProgress showErrorWithStatus:@"problem!" completion:NULL];
                        _passwordField.text = @"";
                    }
                    else if([result.successful boolValue])
                    {
                        [KVNProgress showSuccessWithStatus:result.message];

                    }

});
});
```

It crashed mostly and by surrounding blocks with only Main Queue (no priority default one) that solved! but the problem is:KVNProgress is only showing in error handling area not the next part that we call web service. It's not user friendly at all! Any idea is welcomed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **MUST** call methods that **update the user interface in any way** from the main thread, as per [the `UIKit` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKit_Framework/):

> For the most part, use UIKit classes **only from your app’s main thread**. This is particularly true for classes derived from UIResponder **or that involve manipulating your app’s user interface in any way.**

I suggest you try to limit the number of callbacks you make to the main thread, so therefore you want to **batch as much user interface updates together as you can.**

**Then all you have to do, as you correctly say, is to use a `dispatch_async` to callback to your main thread whenever you need to update the UI, from within your background processing.**

Because it's asynchronous, it won't interrupt your background processing, and should have a minimal interruption on the main thread itself as updating values on most `UIKit` components is fairly cheap, they'll just update their value and trigger their `setNeedsDisplay` so that they'll get re-drawn at the next run loop.

---

From your code, it looks like your issue is that you're calling this from the background thread:

```
if ([_usernameField.text length] < 4) {
    [KVNProgress showErrorWithStatus:@"Username too short!"];
    _passwordField.text = @"";
    return;
}
```

**This is 100% UI updating code, and should therefore take place on the main thread.**

Although, I have no idea about the thread safety of `KVNProgress`, I assume it should also be called on the main thread as it's presenting an error to the user.

Your code therefore should look *something* like this (assuming it's taking place on the main thread to begin with):

```
[KVNProgress show];

//some error handling like:
if ([_usernameField.text length] < 4) {
    [KVNProgress showErrorWithStatus:@"Username too short!"];
    _passwordField.text = @"";
    return;
}

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    //Then I call login web service synchronously here:
    result = [ServerRequests login];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if(!result) {
            [KVNProgress showErrorWithStatus:@"problem!" completion:NULL];
            _passwordField.text = @"";
        } else if([result.successful boolValue]) {
            [KVNProgress showSuccessWithStatus:result.message];
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: did this help @Minoo?